# How can I disable JavaScript in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I am trying to scrape a countdown website using Flutter webscraper package. I successfully scraped the images and titles, but couldn't scrape the timer running, as it changes according to the timer, so after doing some research I saw that if I disable the JavaScript I can scrape the counter but I'm unable to do so..

```java
class _SchedulesState extends State<Schedules> {
    late List<Map<String, dynamic>> scheduleWall = [];
    late List<Map<String, dynamic>> scheduleEpisode = [];
    late List<Map<String, dynamic>> scheduleName = [];
    late List<Map<String, dynamic>> scheduleDay = [];
    late List<Map<String, dynamic>> scheduleHour = [];
    late List<Map<String, dynamic>> scheduleMins = [];

    bool scheduleLoaded = false;
    int page = 1;

    void scheduleFetch() async {
    final scheduleScraper = WebScraper("https://animecountdown.com");
    isJavaScriptSimpleObject(false);

    if (await scheduleScraper.loadWebPage("")) {
      scheduleWall = scheduleScraper.getElement(
        'countdown-content-main-columns-column-items-item-left-poster > img',
        ['src'],
      );

      scheduleName = scheduleScraper.getElement(
        'countdown-content-main-columns-column-items-item-right > countdown-content-main-columns-column-items-item-right-title',
        ['title'],
      );

      scheduleEpisode = scheduleScraper.getElement(
        'countdown-content-main-columns-column-items-item-right > countdown-content-main-columns-column-items-item-right-episode',
        ['title'],
      );
      scheduleDay = scheduleScraper.getElement(
        'div.countdown-item.day > div.countdown-item-number',
        ['title'],
      );
      scheduleHour = scheduleScraper.getElement(
        'div.countdown-item.hour > div.countdown-item-number',
        ['title'],
      );
      scheduleMins = scheduleScraper.getElement(
        'div.countdown-item.min > div.countdown-item-number',
        ['title'],
      );

      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(scheduleName);
      setState(() {
        scheduleLoaded = true;
      });
    }
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scheduleFetch();
      }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff121212),
      body: scheduleLoaded
          ? SafeArea(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Wrap(
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < scheduleWall.length; i++)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 25.0, top: 20.0, right: 25.0, bottom: 20.0),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: "https:" +
                                    scheduleWall[i]['attributes']['src'],
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                colorBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                width: 400,
                                height: 450.0,
                                placeholder: (context, url) {
                                  return const Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: SpinKitPulse(
                                        size: 40.0,
                                        color: Colors.cyan,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(scheduleName[i]['title'],
                                          maxLines: 2,
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 30.0)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 115.0,
                                  ),
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(scheduleEpisode[i]['title'],
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 30.0)),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 140),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 85.0),
                                        child: Text(scheduleEpisode[i]['title'],
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 2.0)),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                                        child: Text(scheduleEpisode[i]['title'],
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 2.0)),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                                        child: Text(scheduleEpisode[i]['title'],
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 2.0)),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    children: const [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 85.0),
                                        child: Text("days",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 20.0)),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                                        child: Text("hours",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 20.0)),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                                        child: Text("mins",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 20.0)),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          : const Center(
              child: SpinKitWanderingCubes(color: Colors.cyanAccent),
            ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would presume that the countdown timer is powered by JavaScript.  If you disable JavaScript, how do you expect that functionality to work on the site at all?

Comment: IF I STOP THE JS EXECUTION I GET THE EXACT DATE AND TIME FOR THE SCHEDULE 

https://ibb.co/Zh1ftr6 HERE IS THE LINK when js is running,

https://ibb.co/7Ghpbn1 and here if I stop the js in my dev tools I get the counter and Can extract it, I hope you understand